# Windows shutdown hangs if UWF enabled

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, uwf

For some reason, when I have UWF enabled, when I restart or shutdown the computer, it goes to the "Restarting" or "Shutting Down" screen with the spinning dots and then just hangs there forever - I've left it for over half an hour without it ever eventually turning off.

However, if I disable UWF, I don't have this problem. Even with UWF enabled, occasionally it shuts down fine but most of the time I get this hanging problem.

Is there a way of figuring out what's causing it to hang? I've tried looking at the Event log, it has very few entries relating to the shutdown -

- System

  1. The Shutdown being initiated
  2. Logoff Notification for CEIP (even though I've disabled CEIP)
  3. Stopping Event Log service
- Application

  1. Closing MSSQL
  2. "Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services"  (Possible reason? But it also says "No User Action is required".)
  3. The User Profile Service has stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been related to Windows Defender.

After disabling this, I don't encounter this issue any more.